# What is the proper way of changing states in react for loading animations from the beginning of a GET request to the end of it?

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to trigger a load animation in React and perform a GET request, and then stop the loading animation after the get request completed. This is how I laid out my code.

```
export default class Dialog extends Component {
  state = {
    domIdx: 0
  }

  loadData = () => {
    this.setState({
      domIdex: 1
    }, $.getJSON('http://google.com', () => {
      this.setState({
        domIdx: 2  
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    let arr = [<UploadFile/>, <LoadAnimation/>, <Done/>]        

    return (
      <div>
        {arr[this.state.domIdx]}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However, the above code is not working after the loading animation is triggered. The loading animation is shown, the GET request is completed, but the view doesn't change after calling setState again.

How can I achieve the intended action?

Answer (score 0):

In your component state, you can define a loading piece of state:

```
state = { loading: false }
```

Then, when you make your request, flip it to to true:

```
loadData = () => {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    }, $.getJSON('http://google.com', () => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false  
      })
    })
  }
```

Then in your render:

```
 render() {      

    return (
      <div>
      {this.state.loading ? (<SomeSpinner />):(<Completed />)}

      </div>
    )
  }
```